# Rcpp::abs defaults to int instead of double?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpp11

Source the following cpp file in RStudio and you see that Rcpp::abs is returning an integer when I was hoping for a double. std::abs solves the issue. I assume my expectation is wrong, but why is that? Why should it return an integer here (granted, it's a double, but can only take integer values)?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector closestIndices(NumericVector x) {
  int fst = 0;
  int snd = 1;
  int n = x.size();
  double diff = abs(x[snd] - x[fst]);
  Rprintf("diff: %f\n", diff);
  double candDiff;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
      candDiff = abs(x[j] - x[i]);
      // Rprintf("i: %i\tj: %i\tdiff: %.4f\n", i, j,candDiff);
      if( candDiff < diff){
        fst = i;
        snd = j;
        diff = candDiff;
      }
    }
  }
  
  NumericVector output = {double(fst),double(snd)};
  return output;
}

/*** R
x <- c(0.98799517, 1.09055728, 1.20383713, 1.32927166, 1.46857509, 
       1.62380423, 1.79743107, 1.99241551, 2.21226576, 2.46106916, 2.74346924, 
       3.06455219, 3.42958354, 3.84350238, 4.31005838, 4.83051356, 5.40199462, 
       6.01590035, 6.65715769, 7.30532785, 7.93823621, 8.53773241, 9.09570538, 
       9.61755743, 10.12099196, 10.6301818, 11.16783243, 11.74870531, 
       12.37719092, 13.04922392, 13.75661322, 14.49087793, 15.24414627, 
       16.00601247, 16.75709565, 17.46236358, 18.06882072, 18.51050094, 
       18.71908344, 18.63563523, 18.22123225, 17.46709279, 16.40246292, 
       15.09417699, 13.63404124, 12.11854915, 10.6305417, 9.22947285, 
       7.95056, 6.80923943, 5.80717982, 4.93764782, 4.1894745, 3.54966795, 
       3.00499094, 2.54283599, 2.1516578, 1.82114213, 1.54222565, 1.30703661, 
       1.10879707, 0.94170986, 0.80084308, 0.68201911, 0.58171175, 0.49695298, 
       0.42525021, 0.3645135, 0.31299262, 0.26922281, 0.2319786, 0.20023468, 
       0.17313291, 0.14995459, 0.1300973, 0.11305559, 0.09840485, 0.08578789, 
       0.07490387, 0.06549894, 0.05735864)
closestIndices(x)
*/
```

Comment: It is what it is.  C++ wraps around C, C had `abs()` for `int` and `fabs()` for `double`.  As you already stated you want `std::abs()` from more modern C++ -- or possibly even `Rcpp::abs()` which is vectorised too.  

Morale:  Be careful with namespaces, and explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Also, only noticed this now, your 'title' is wrong. As you called `abs(x)` with `x` being `double`, you did *not* call `Rcpp::abs()` as there is no such signature in that namespace.

Comment: I thought `abs` would default to `Rcpp:abs` since it's explicitly stated as a sugared expression for folks to use. Not the case, eh? Ok. I can live with that. Obviously, there's a lot about Rcpp I don't know. Thank you for making such a kickass package!

Comment: No it is a C++ feature that function name _and signature_ must match. And you called with C types, so you get  the C function.